# How is the surface charge density calculated at a point?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

I've currently worked on a problem where I had to find the surface charge density at the origin on a grounded plane $z = 0$ that's horizontally oriented. Above this plane on a distance $h$ is also a horizontally oriented thin and circular ring with line charge density $\rho_l$ and radius $a$. The center of the ring is right above the origin. Something like this:

[image]

I managed to find the electric field through the origin to be $\frac{-\rho_l a h}{\epsilon_0 (h^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$ which was correct according to the solution presented. However, then I became a bit confused on how to calculate the surface charge density at the origin, since I can't recall any formula that would help me do that. I first thought of using the displacement field for this, however, since there's no information about permittivity given in the problem, I knew that can't be right.

I then turned to Gauss law, but calculating the divergence of my electric field would just be $0$ and so that would give me a surface charge density of $0$.

I eventually looked at the whole solution presented and found that they just set that electric field $\frac{-\rho_l a h}{\epsilon_0 (h^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$ equal to $\rho_s/\epsilon_0$ and solved for $\rho_s$ which is the surface charge density at the origin. This reminds me of Gauss, but there's no divergence. What's happening here really?

Comment: since you can never "calculate" the density at a point  by the charge induced you would have ti take the limit over the density in a small area around 0, so the way to calculate it  by E is the easier way

Comment: @trula I guess taking the limit over the density as you described is what is then used to derive the electrostatic boundary conditions that Michael referred to? In that case, I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [electrostatic boundary conditions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274318/is-there-a-more-rigorous-derivation-of-the-electrostatic-boundary-conditions?rq=1), which relate the charge density on any surface to the discontinuity of the electric field across that surface.  In your case, the surface in question is the grounded plane;  you also need to remember that the electric field *below* the plane is exactly zero.

The reason that this condition reminds you of Gauss's Law is that the integral form of Gauss's Law is used to derive them.  See the link above for the details.

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure of why we can say that the potential below the plane is $0$. Why isn't it $0$ on just the plane? Can you think of it as we added the ring with some line charge density, then we added the plane and so the ring induced an electric field and a charge that's of opposite sign over the plate. Then we ground the plane, but the charge is still on the plate. If we then calculate the E-field using a Gaussian surface including the plane, the enclosed charge is 0, thus E = 0 and constant potential, hence 0 to match the boundary of the plate?

Comment: @Tanamas:  I'm having trouble visualizing your procedure.  But the simplest argument to see why $\vec{E} = 0$ below the plane is as follows:  $V = 0$ on the plane, and $V \to 0$ as we go to infinity.  There are no charges in the "lower" half of space, so $\nabla^2 V = 0$ everywhere in that half-space.  The only way to satisfy these conditions for the lower half-space is to have $V = 0$ everywhere, which means $\vec{E} = 0$ everywhere below the plane.

Comment: Now I see why that's the case. Thank you for your time, I understand it much better now.